# Strapi bulk add default value for a new UID field

Tags: postgresql, strapi

I have a Strapi v4 app using a PostgreSQL database in production.

My app has a collection called: `places`.

Initially I created the collection with fields: title, description, image etc.

I've now found that I also need a `slug` field which uses the UID datatype.

After creating it, it "magically" adds a slug to every new instance of `places` created by users or directly in the admin panel.

But I can't figure out how to update the existing ~200 `places`.  I know there isn't a bulk update option but does anyone have a decent way to do this without going through each manually?